# How to import actuator httptrace in actuator prometheus? (actuator, spring boot, grafana)

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer, http-trace

Imagine this is my http://localhost:8080/actuator ouotput:

```
{
"_links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/actuator",
        "templated": false
    },
    "health": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/actuator/health",
        "templated": false
    },
    "prometheus": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/actuator/prometheus",
        "templated": false
    },
    "httptrace": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/actuator/httptrace",
        "templated": false
    }
}
}
```

Now I've hooked up my prometheus environment to `/actuator/prometheus` and that works fine. I als want prometheus to read my httptrace so I also added `/actuator/httptrace` to my prometheus config. However this does not work. The formatting on the httptrace endpoint [is in json](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/actuator-api/html/#http-trace-retrieving) and the formatting in prometheus [is in yaml](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/actuator-api/html/#prometheus), I think I need the httptrace in the prometheus yaml. Prometheus eats the yaml just fine, the json not so much.

How can I pass my httptrace to actuator/prometheus from my spring boot project? In the end my goal is to get the timeTaken value for every request in grafana.

Comment: Prometheus is ingesting [open metrics](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats/#text-based-format) format, neither yaml nor json will work. Also Prometheus is a time serie database, it is not intended to trace every request but rather have some metrics through the use of histograms or summaries.

Comment: Yes I figired so, thanks Michael. I hoped there is some easy way to convert the json data into the open metrics format, but I don't think that is possible. As for plan B I'm going to use micrometer to create my own custom metrics that will be added to the prometheus endpoint. With the AOP @Around annotation I can time the controller function to know how long it took. It will be more work but it's doable.

Comment: @scre_www did you get any way to how plot a graph for httptrace in grafana?

Answer (score 1):

Spring's HttpTraceRepository exposes the recent traces on an endpoint but not in prometheus as percentiles. So I can suggest two paths:

1. You implement your own `HttpTraceRepository` that wraps the one your using (default is InMemory....) and then override the method to fire off some custom `Timer` from [io.micrometer.core] with the timing (https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_timers) which will get aggregated as percentiles if you also enable via https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.metrics.customizing.per-meter-properties

> In the end my goal is to get the timeTaken value for every request in grafana.

2. **Just use http_server_requests_seconds_* that are captured per endpoint** (not request)

**http_server_requests_seconds_count**
is the total number of requests your application received at this endpoint

**http_server_requests_seconds_sum**
is the sum of the the duration of every request your application received at this endpoint

and this great post explains how to use it in prometheus, https://tomgregory.com/spring-boot-default-metrics/